# How to do Next Page if its using Javascript in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having a problem with the crawling the next button I tried the basic one but after checking the html code, its uses javascript I've tried different rules but nothing works here's the link for the website.

https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html

The next button name is "Load More Products"

here's my working code

```
def parse(self, response):
    for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
        url = "https://www2.hm.com/" + product_item.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first() 
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_subpage)

def parse_subpage(self, response):
    item = {
    'title': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//h1[contains(@class, 'primary') and contains(@class, 'product-item-headline')]/text())").extract_first(),
    'sale-price': response.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='price-value']/text())").extract_first(), 
    'regular-price': response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "whitePrice")]/text()').re_first("'whitePrice'\s?:\s?'([^']+)'"),
    'photo-url': response.css('div.product-detail-main-image-container img::attr(src)').extract_first(),
    'description': response.css('p.pdp-description-text::text').extract_first()

        }   
    yield item
```

Comment: Scrapy doen't run JavaScript - you may have to use Selenium to control web browser which will load page and JavaScript. Or use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see what url is used when you click button. And then you can load from this url. Mostly it will send data as JSON so it will be much easier to get data. JSON can be easily converted to Python's dictionary

Comment: This button uses url https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/women/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting_b48c.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=36&page-size=36

Comment: @furas how to move to the next page during scraping?

Comment: you don't move to next page - you create `Reqest()` with url which uses button. And Scrapy will read JSON data like button does. You could even use this url to read first page - there is parameter `offset` in url which probably can read different pages.

Comment: Try this `https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=3002` to get all of them with the way you have already tried. The main key here is this portion `page-size=` which is incremented `36` each time you click on that button until it is `3002`.

Comment: Thanks @SIM wonder if I can make 3002 be dynamic like if I use response.css for that. I am trying that code but I didnt get the exact value

Answer (score 1):

As already hinted in the comments, there's no need to involve JavaScript at all. If you visit the page and open up your browser's developer tools, you'll see there are XHR requests like this taking place:

```
https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/women/view-all/_jcr_content/main/productlisting_b48c.display.json?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=36&page-size=36
```

These requests return JSON data that are then rendered on the page using JavaScript. So you can just scrape data from these URLs using something like `json.dumps(response.text)`. Control the products being returned by `offset` and `page-size` parameters. I assume you are done when you receive an empty JSON. Or, you can set `offset=0` and `page-size=9999` to get the data in one go (`9999` is just an arbitrary number which is enough in this particular case).

Comment: Hi @tomas thank you for answering me wonder if I can make the page-size dynamically change based on the html given. ill get it through response.css is that possibe? I am trying the code but nothing's happen

Comment: @ChristianRead You don't need to mess with HTML at all as far as I can tell, all the information is in JSON returned by the API  call. The JSON response also contains field `total` which you can use to determined when to stop (e.g. `(offset + 1) * page-size <= 3002` where `3002` is the value of `total` field currently being returned.

Comment: Sorry and thank you for helping me @Tomas, but my problem is the page-size is constantly changing so for example 3002 can be change to 3004 that's why I am wondering if I can make 3002 dynamic. The total number of page is shown on the html so I am thinking that I can use it.

Comment: Well, than just paginate as you would normally do, i.e. call the API with `offset` increasing and fixed `page-size` e.g. 100. Every response contains `total` field so you can check if you are at the end. Also, it returns `itemsShown` counter which can also be used for that. There are multiple ways.